# cross domain call with jQuery jsonp to ASP.NET web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, jsonp

I've tried so many examples but still stuck.

I'm trying to call a cross domain ws call using Ajax Jquery but get back the following error:

My Ajax call is :

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var para = JSON.stringify({ orgname: var0, ccGuid: var1 , accountTypeGuid: var2 });

   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:http://example:5052/WebServices/CustomerView.asmx/GetCustomerPlans,
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: para,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            'withCredentials': true
       },
        success: UpdateCustomerViews,
        error: fail
    });
```

Passed Parameters are :

```
{"orgname":"abc","ccGuid":"4194716f-a068-e411-80c1-0050568c48b6","accountTypeGuid":"a53cd1ca-716a-e411-80c2-0050568c48b6"}
```

url showing in fiddler :

```
http://example:5052/WebServices/CustomerView.asmx/GetCustomerPlans?callback=jQuery110203820646793817735_1448975800168&  {"orgname":"abc","ccGuid":"4194716f-a068-e411-80c1-0050568c48b6","accountTypeGuid":"8d89ffdf-91d7-e411-80d0-0050568c48b6"}&_=1448975800169
```

My webMethod :

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetCustomerPlans(string orgname, string ccGuid, string accountTypeGuid)
    {
           //some Buisness logic
           JavaScriptSerializer javascipt = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           string result = javascipt.Serialize(CCIDs.ToArray());
           return result;           
    }
```

Error Message Showing in the Fiddler :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: orgname.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection
>   collection)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Please suggest where I am making the mistake.

FYI : The Original working code is given below, It is working well but it was failing in Chrome and Mozila, I came to know about cross origin policy issue, then I decided to change the same code for JSONP.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var para = JSON.stringify({ orgname: var0, ccGuid: var1 , accountTypeGuid: var2 });

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:http://example:5052/WebServices/CustomerView.asmx/GetCustomerPlans,
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: para,
        dataType: "json",           
        xhrFields: {
            'withCredentials': true
       },
        success: UpdateCustomerViews,
        error: fail
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

please try not to use JSON.stringify

try this

`var para = {"orgname":"abc","ccGuid":"4194716f-a068-e411-80c1-0050568c48b6","accountTypeGuid":"a53cd1ca-716a-e411-80c2-0050568c48b6"}`

Your stacktrace shows that your parameters are not in correct format.

Comment: thanks for quick reply but suggested solution did't work for me.

Comment: After removing JSON.stringify parameters string created : 
[link](http://example:5052/WebServices/CustomerView.asmx/GetCustomerPlans?callback=jQuery110203820646793817735_1448975800168&  orgname=abc&ccGuid=4194716f-a068-e411-80c1-0050568c48b6&accountTypeGuid=8d89ffdf-91d7-e411-80d0-0050568c48b6&_=1448975800169) and now showing Authorization Error.